# List Custom Taxonomy Values according to a Post Meta Value

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta

I' having a **custom post type** with **custom taxonomy**. In the Post I've specified a post meta value (via `update_post_meta`) that has the value '0' or '1' (it's a checkbox).

Now I'm trying to generate a list of taxonomy values which have posts assigned to them **and the post meta value is set to '1'**.

Is there a way I can hook into `wp_list_categories` and pass post specific values as a filter parameter? Or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of taxonomies? Or a list of posts?

Comment: A list of taxonomies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return an array of term objects, if you need these processed to be hierarchical or something, that's pretty easy, I think the challenge you were having was getting the term objects.

```
//get posts
$args = array(
    //basic stuff
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //meta query
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'your_key',
            'value'   => '1'
        )
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

//get categories from posts and amalgamate them
$categories = array();
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    $new_cats = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'your-taxonomy-slug' );
    $categories = array_merge(
        $categories,
        array_diff(
            $categories,
            $new_cats
        )
    );
}
```

I feel like there might be something that you could do with the `get_terms` hook, but I can't put my finger on it (shy of querying for every term to see if it has posts that meet the condition, but that's way less efficient than my method I think).

Comment: Thank's! You definitely pointed me in the right direction. Your example returns an empty array and I think it's because the arrays from the `wp_get_object_terms` function always differ (eg. by [term_id]). Anyway I can push the values I need in a Array programmatically and it works like a charm!

Comment: Hurr, interesting...I didn't test it at all, just wrote the code right off and pasted it in, so it may be a dumb error...it might also be something to do with `array_diff()` not being able to compare objects...I'll make sure to do some testing if I ever need it! Glad you got it working!