# Store and Work with huge array in WP

Tags: php, database, options

I need to get all terms that have post with dates in custom field.
So I need a list for all dates from the term.
I need to know exactly what is tha dates within each term in my site.
It's not in term, it's in their posts.

after that I need to know foreach month what is the terms that containe post with this specifc month.

all of this is needed for search's fields to filter my post type (tours) by terms (country) and dates (each tour can have many dates).

I got the solution bymyself in another post: 
[get terms that have post with custom post type between 2 values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228742/get-terms-that-have-post-with-custom-post-type-between-2-values)

Now I need to know hot to store this huge array in my Wordpress Database.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea and bad practice but just so readers understand, are you saying when you pass the array to `update_option()` it gives you a white screen or some kind of error? Can you edit your question ( by click the above `edit` button ) and add some more detail as to what is happening?

Comment: I edit my question and add information

Comment: Why are you storing this data as an option instead of using the built-in [`post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) and [`term_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_term_meta)?

Comment: because after all of this I need to know foreach month what is the terms that containe posts that have daates from this month.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/322985). Can you edit your question and describe how your system works and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: This would give you certain errors e.g `MySQL server has gone away` for that the data is large. Have you considered chunking data into batches and store 1000~2000 values per option? [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is perfect for this.. Then later join data..

Comment: I edit my question and let you know why i need it.

Comment: @GuyYtzhak Just so I understand your predicament: You have post type `tours` where the user lists many dates as custom fields. Each post has a category `country`. You're trying to get all countries that have posts with tours available in a certain month, like June. If that's correct then you're trying to get terms by posts postmeta ( custom fields ) and something [like this may be useful](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42690/7355). This gets all posts by a meta_value ( month in your example ) then grabs the unique categories and stores them in an array.

Comment: thats right!
I do It and I save all of this in array, but the array gone to be bigger!
But you make me thinking about split all this to 24 or 36 array, each array foreach month from now to next 2-3 years. and each array containe all terms that include this month in them!
Thanks!
But now, that's mean that I need to create 36 posts loops :(

Comment: Could you provide an example of specific user workflow? Possible solution would be _significantly_ different depending on desired functionality and order/complexity of queries.

Comment: When user go to each page of my webste, he see in the header the search form.
This search form prove two select boxes: Months and Countires.
If youe select the month "May, 2017" the select box of countires changes and display only countires that have tours in this month.
It's need to work if you select fcountry like Inida it's let you choose the dates for India Only.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell your needs are completely unsupported by WP API.

Taxonomies in WP are a *grouping* mechanism. Their primary purpose is to query set of objects, belonging to a group (term) or groups. There is no *reverse* operation to provide a set of objects and inquire *which* groups (terms) it belongs to.

On top of that your logic requires additional hop to meta data **and** to be able to do it in both ways (restrict countries by date, as well as restrict dates by countries).

I see three possible approaches here (complexity ascending):

1. Drop the chained requirement. Let users select date and country freely, inform them if there are no results for particular combination. Even Google sometimes says it didn't found anything.
2. Crunch the data with API async and cache the relationship data in some form.
3. Write custom SQL that implements the necessary logic with reasonable performance.

*Personally* I would go with 3 in such situation, but only because I am reasonably confident I can write and maintain such SQL.

Comment: Ok,
I know that is not wp api support for this. So I create a function that get all of this to array, and this is a large array. so the first question is how to store and work with huge arrays. I edit my question many time to explaine it to you and I return to my first question. How to work and store big array in WP DB to display it in my site and in my custom requirements ?
So why you edit my question? Its not what I need to do.
I also get all this posts and terms and dates in my array. My problem is to work with huge array in regular server.

Comment: Options API? Not like there are that many storage options in WP. As I answered I would prefer SQL route myself, it is hard for me to estimate sane solution for intermediary caching approach without working with specific data.

Comment: I got all the data by functions. So you think I need to work my my array? see in the question (I edit the question) or maybe I can create a CLASS and call to functions within the class foreach term?